# KVM Switch Under Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: usb, keyboard, 14.04, mouse, kvm-switch

I'm trying to install a KVM Switch between two computer. The first one runs under Windows XP. The mouse/keyboard/screen works perfectly (the first computer is an ACER Aspire (Lifestyle Line)). When I switch to the second computer (Dell Optiplex 745 with Ubuntu 14.04) the screen switch, but the USB Wireless Keyboard/Mouse stop working. I can access and navigate the Bios with the KB/M connected to the switch.

When I Plug the USB directly (without the KVM Switch) it works perfectly.

Also, the screen is a Flatron L1510S (Touch Screen), it has a PS/2 plug that controls the mouse (it's connected directly to the first computer as it's the only one that needs touch screen)

Everything is USB except for that wire.

I think the problem comes from the OS but I can't seem to figure out why. All the USB ports work perfectly except for when the source is the switch.

Anybody had a similar problem before?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Does the switch work if you switch the ports (run Ubuntu on the working cable where the windows box is currently and try to switch to windows). Does the box work if you boot windows on the ubuntu box ?

Comment: As of now the XP computer is in use so I can't make any physical change on it (the screen is a terminal in a restaurant). But you would think it might be the connector/wire that is  broken, or the computer). If it's the computer, why would I be able to use the keyboard in the BIOS? Does it load the USB differently?

Comment: Oh, and for now, Ubuntu is the only OS on the Ubuntu box.

Comment: OK well test the ubuntu box on a known good set of cables.

Comment: Will do, I'll repost as soon as I have access to the computers

Comment: May we have the model and maker of the KVM switch ?
Not every KVM switches created equally. In order to solve the issue, the correct input of KVM switch is important.

Comment: t was a noname chinese knock-off. It broke in a matter of a month. Replaced with a popular brand one and everything works